# Преобразовать код под Vue.js

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vue3

У меня есть функция на JQuery:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
    $(document).mouseup(function(e){
        let item = $(".dropdown.open");
        if (item.has(e.target).length === 0){
            item.removeClass('open');
        }
    })
});
```

Можно ли ее как-то преобразовать чтобы она работала на Vue.js 3 ?

Я думал в верстке на каждый div[.dropdown-toggle] сделать типа

```
<div class="dropdown-toggle" @click="function...">...
```

На так как таких блоков много, я думаю это не лучшее решение.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

**UPD.** Вот что у меня получилось:

```
    mounted() {
        let dropdowns = this.$el.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-toggle');
        dropdowns.forEach(dropdown => {
            dropdown.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                let parent = event.target.closest('.dropdown');
                parent.classList.toggle("open");
            });
        });
    }
```

Но не могу понять как сделать чтобы класс **open** удалялся если кликнуть в любом другом месте страницы...

**UPD.** получилось сделать таким образом

```
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', event => {
            const opened_dropdown = this.$el.querySelector('.dropdown.open');
            if (opened_dropdown) {
                if ( !opened_dropdown.contains(event.target) ) {
                    opened_dropdown.classList.remove("open");
                }
            }
        }, false);
```

Огромная просьба - если видите какие-то недостатки такого решения, или есть более изящный вариант, напишите в ответ.

Answer (score 2):

В вашем коде нет слушателя события клика на `document`, чтобы закрыть все выпадающие списки при клике в любом месте страницы, и потому выпадающие списки оставались открытыми после того, как их открыли.

```
mounted() {
  // Add click listener to document
  document.addEventListener('click', this.closeDropdowns);

  // Add click listener to each .dropdown-toggle
  let dropdowns = this.$el.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-toggle');
  dropdowns.forEach(dropdown => {
    dropdown.addEventListener('click', event => {
      let parent = event.target.closest('.dropdown');
      parent.classList.toggle("open");
    });
  });
},
methods: {
  closeDropdowns(event) {
    // Check if click was inside a dropdown
    let dropdowns = this.$el.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');
    dropdowns.forEach(dropdown => {
      if (!dropdown.contains(event.target)) {
        dropdown.classList.remove('open');
      }
    });
  }
},
beforeUnmount() {
  // Remove click listener from document when component is removed
  document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeDropdowns);
}
```

Что касаемо вашего обновленного кода - лучше использовать `document` вместо `window`, потому что `document` является родительским элементом всех элементов на странице, что обеспечивает более точную проверку клика вне списка. Ну и лучше использовать `mousedown` вместо `mouseup`, потому что `mousedown` происходит раньше, чем `mouseup`, что в свою очередь может снизить мерцание интерфейса.

**Используя стрелочные функции:**

```
mounted() {
  let dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-toggle');
  dropdowns.forEach(dropdown => {
    let clickHandler = event => {
      let parent = event.target.closest('.dropdown');
      parent.classList.toggle("open");
    };
    dropdown.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
  });
},
beforeUnmount() {
  let dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-toggle');
  dropdowns.forEach(dropdown => {
    let clickHandler = event => {
      let parent = event.target.closest('.dropdown');
      parent.classList.toggle("open");
    };
    dropdown.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler);
  });
}
```

Сохраняем ссылку на анонимную функцию, переданную в `addEventListener` в переменной, чтобы далее использовать ее в `removeEventListener`.

Comment: а обязательно ли удалять события ( removeEventListener ) ? зачем?

Comment: @iKey Желательно удалять,  чтобы избежать утечек памяти

Comment: в removeEventListener вторым аргументом обязательно передавать функцию которую вешали? как тогда мне удалить событие если я не вешаю заранее созданную функцию, а создаю ее сразу как вешаю событие `dropdown.addEventListener('click', event => { ... });` ?

Comment: @iKey Да, обязательно. В removeEventListener нужно передавать ту же функцию, которая была передана при добавлении слушателя событий

Comment: а как тогда удалить событие если его вешали так `dropdown.addEventListener('click', event => { ... })` ? то есть название функции не передавали

Comment: @iKey можно сохранить функцию в переменной и потом использовать ее в removeEventListener

Comment: а, если название функции не передавали тогда только через анонимную функцию в removeEventListener

Comment: можете, пожалуйста, привести пример?

Comment: @iKey обновил код